# Performance degradation after migrating application from .net 5.0 to .net 6.0

Tags: performance-testing, .net-6.0

I have upgraded my payment application from .Net 5.0 to .Net 6.0 without any single line of code changes. I performed stress test using jmeter on both pre migration and post migration releases.

The stress results of post migration are showing degradation in 2 respects, when users were 100-200 and duration was 5 mins:

1. lower TPS (Transaction per second)
2. High CPU usage

Am I missing something? Do i need to do some server level configurations to make my application give best results with .net6.0?

---

UPDATES:

The high CPU usage issue is resolved, which was due to a costly database call in one of the application. But still I cannot see any difference in  the TPS, infact TPS is a bit dropped in .net 6.0.

I have set the below variables:

```
set DOTNET_ReadyToRun=0 
set DOTNET_TieredPGO=1 
set DOTNET_TC_QuickJitForLoops=1
```

Still no difference in performance can be seen. Pls. suggest.

Answer (score 2):

It shouldn't be the case, looking at [Performance Improvements in .NET 6](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/performance-improvements-in-net-6/) article your app should work faster.

If you're absolutely sure that the lower TPS is caused by higher CPU usage you need to use a profiler tool like [YourKit](https://www.yourkit.com/.net/profiler/features/) or an [APM tool](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/getting-the-full-application-picture-with-blazemeter-and-apm-integration) to see what exactly causes the CPU usage or slowdown.

You also can try setting the following options:

```
set DOTNET_ReadyToRun=0 
set DOTNET_TieredPGO=1 
set DOTNET_TC_QuickJitForLoops=1
```

Comment: where these options needs to be set ?